# getting and EOF code at the end and can't figure out why?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I'm trying to write a program to determine the body-mass index of a collection of six individuals. Your program should include a list of six names. Using a for loop, it should successively prompt the user for the height in inches and weight in pounds of each individual. Each prompt should include the name of the individual whose height and weight is to be input. It should call a function that accepts the height and weight as parameters and returns the body mass index for that individual using the formula weight × 703 / height2. That body mass index should then be appended to an array. Using a second loop it should traverse the array of body mass indices and call another function that accepts the body mass index as a parameter and returns whether the individual is underweight, normal weight or overweight. The number of individuals in each category should be counted and the number in each of those categories should be displayed. You should decide on the names of the six individuals and the thresholds used for categorization.
i have wrote a code but it will give me a EOF code at the end, and i cant figure out why.

```
 def bmi(weight, height):
 bmi = weight * 703 / height**2
 bmi = round(pay,2)
 return bmi

 def cata(bmi):
 for num in bmi:
 if number >= 16 and bmi < 18.5:
 category.append('underweight')
 elif( bmi >= 18.5 and bmi < 25):
 category.append('normal') 
 elif( bmi > 25):
 category.append(overweight)

 names = ['john', 'zack', 'mike', 'Tim', 'Zain', 'jenny']

 height = []
 weight = []

 bmi_results = array("d",[])

category = []

for employee in names:
height = float(input('what is {employee}s height'))
weight = float(input('what is {employee}s weight'))
height.append(height)
weight.append(weight)
bmi_results.append(bmi(height,weight))

cata(bmi_results)
underweight =category.count('underweight')
normal = category.count('normal')
overweight = category.count(overweight)

if underweight == 1:
  print(f"there are{underweight} employees")
if underweight > 1:
  print(f"there are {underweight} number of employees")
if normal == 1:
  print(f"the are {normal} number of employess")
if normal > 1:
  print(f"there are {normal} number of employees")
if overweight == 1:
  print(f"there are {overweight} number of employees")
if overweight > 1:
   print(f"there are {overweight} number of employees")

 for name in names:
  x = names.index(name)
  print(f"At {height[x]:.2f} and {weight[x]:.2f}, {names} is 
  {category[x]} with a bmi {bmi_results[x]:.2f}.")
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: What's your question? Please [edit] to clarify. If this is homework, please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: i have a eoor at the end of my code and cant figure out why

Comment: Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236. "I can't figure out why" isn't an adequate question, and "I have this kind of error" isn't an adequate description of the problem

Comment: Anyway, you should carefully look at that last line of code, where the complaint occurs: `print(f"At {height[x]:.2f} and {weight[x]:.2f}, {names} is 
  {category[x]} with a bmi {bmi_results[x]:.2f}."` See anything missing at the end there? Hint: what is the very next thing that appears after `print`? Does that need to match up with something else?

Comment: i have fixed that issue but its  still having a error

Comment: I urge y'all not to close this question. The OP is trying really hard. Yes, I get that the OP may not be providing clarity we may be used to or we may desire. It can be frustrating. Stay with the OP. I really hope we can get OP to solve the problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I was tempted to write this answer because when I was learning coding this kind of question came up and it took me weeks to figure it out. I wish someone was available to explain it step by step. Hopefully this answer helps you.

There are a few pieces missing from your code. Let's review the questions and write the corresponding code and build upon the code you wrote.

## Your program should include a list of six names.

You can either create a list and add 6 names or you can prompt for 6 names.

To add 6 names in a list can be done by writing: `people = ['Mary', 'John' ...]`

You can also prompt the names from the user like so:

```
print('==> I am going to ask you for 6 people''s names now')
number_of_people = 6
people = []
for person_number in range(number_of_people):
    person_name = input(f'Name of user {person_number + 1} of {number_of_people}: ')
    people.append(person_name) # storing the person's name
```

---

## Ask for height and weight

You have to use a loop to ask for height in inches and weight in pounds of each person along with their names.

You can do that by doing something like this:

```
print('==> Let''s get the height and name for each person')
bmis = []
for person in people:
    print(f'=====> Give me the height(in) and weight(lbs) for {person}')
    height = float(input(f'Height (inches): '))
    weight = float(input(f'Weight (lbs): '))
```

---

## Get BMI

Since you have to create a function to calculate BMI and use it in the loop above, let's do that.

Write the BMI function.

```
def get_bmi(height, weight):
    return weight * 703 / (height * height)
```

Then, include it in your loop like so:

```
print('==> Let''s get the height and name for each person')
bmis = []
for person in people:
    print(f'=====> Give me the height(in) and weight(lbs) for {person}')
    height = float(input(f'Height (inches): '))
    weight = float(input(f'Weight (lbs): '))
    person_bmi = get_bmi(height, weight)     # get the BMI
    bmis.append(person_bmi)                  # store the BMI
    #print(f'BMI of {person} is {person_bmi}')
```

We also added the BMI to an array/list as asked.

---

## Loop through BMI and get weight class

First you need a function that returns weight class. Let's do that.

```
def get_weight_classification(person_bmi):
    if person_bmi < 16:
        return 'severly underweight';
    if person_bmi >= 16 and person_bmi < 18.5:
        return 'underweight'
    if person_bmi >= 18.5 and person_bmi < 25:
        return 'normal'

    return 'overweight'
```

Then, loop through BMI and use this function. As we loop through BMI and get weight class, we will enter that in a dictionary. If that weight class is already in the dictionary, increment its value by one. If it is not in the dictionary, add it and give it a value of 1

```
weight_classes = {}
for person_bmi in bmis:
    weight_class = get_weight_classification(person_bmi)  # get the weight class

    # if the weight class is already in the dictionary called weight_classes
    # add 1 to the existing value of that weight class
    # otherwise, add the weight class with a count of 1
    if weight_class in weight_classes:
        weight_classes[weight_class] += 1
    else:
        weight_classes[weight_class] = 1
```

Using a second loop it should traverse the array of body mass indices and call another function that accepts the body mass index as a parameter and returns whether the individual is underweight, normal weight or overweight.

---

## Print the results

Now you should just print the results.

```
print('===== RESULTS =====')
for weight_class in weight_classes:
    print(f"{weight_class}: {weight_classes[weight_class]}")
```

---

## Full code

```
def get_bmi(height, weight):
    return weight * 703 / (height * height)

# -------------------------

def get_weight_classification(person_bmi):
    if person_bmi < 16:
        return 'severly underweight';
    if person_bmi >= 16 and person_bmi < 18.5:
        return 'underweight'
    if person_bmi >= 18.5 and person_bmi < 25:
        return 'normal'
    
    return 'overweight'

# -------------------------

print('==> I am going to ask you for 6 people''s names now')
number_of_people = 6
people = []
for person_number in range(number_of_people):
    person_name = input(f'Name of user {person_number + 1} of {number_of_people}: ')
    people.append(person_name) # storing the person's name

# -------------------------

print('')
print('')
print('==> Let''s get the height and name for each person')
bmis = []
for person in people:
    print(f'=====> Give me the height(in) and weight(lbs) for {person}')
    height = float(input(f'Height (inches): '))
    weight = float(input(f'Weight (lbs): '))
    person_bmi = get_bmi(height, weight)     # get the BMI
    bmis.append(person_bmi)                  # store the BMI
    #print(f'BMI of {person} is {person_bmi}')

# -------------------------

# get weight classification for each BMI and count
weight_classes = {}
for person_bmi in bmis:
    weight_class = get_weight_classification(person_bmi)  # get the weight class

    # if the weight class is already in the dictionary called weight_classes
    # add 1 to the existing value of that weight class
    # otherwise, add the weight class with a count of 1
    if weight_class in weight_classes:                    
        weight_classes[weight_class] += 1
    else:
        weight_classes[weight_class] = 1

# -------------------------

# print count
print('')
print('')
print('===== RESULTS =====')
for weight_class in weight_classes:
    print(f"{weight_class}: {weight_classes[weight_class]}")
```

Comment: here is my code i wrote but getting an eol error at the end can not figur out why

Comment: @dbaby  you are welcome to edit your question and include new code that shows EOL error. Make sure the code you type in your question has correct indentation. You can type your code in your question, select the code text and press CTRL+K on Windows or Command+K to automatically format it as code.

Comment: i have edit my original question and updated my code still getting the EOF error

Comment: Please don't answer like this. The actual question being asked about is caused by a simple typo; the questions you are addressing are... a lot of questions, and only one is supposed to be asked at a time. Either way, the question is supposed to be closed, not answered. Please read [answer] and keep in mind that this is *not a discussion forum*.

Comment: @dbaby Make sure that the last `print` statement is all in one line. Replace `bmi_results = array("d",[])` with `bmi_results = []`. Change `height = []` to `heights = []`. Change `weight = []` to `weights = []`. There are other changes you will have to make too.

Comment: i have fixed this but still have errors else where

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I am content with my answer and made a conscious decision to answer, as mentioned in the first paragraph. Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful. I don't like closing questions where I see OP trying hard to solve a problem. Not everyone can convey their thoughts clearly.

Comment: @dbaby yes, that is expected. Change `bmi_results = array("d",[])` to `bmi_results = []`. Change `bmi = round(pay,2)` to `bmi = round(bmi,2)`. Change `if number >= 16 and bmi < 18.5:` to `if num >= 16 and num < 18.5:`. In the elif statements, use num instead of bmi. Change `category.append(overweight)` to `category.append('overweight')`.

Comment: @dbaby do you need any additional help?